# How do you get zen encoding to work for VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So I downloaded the Web Essentials extension for VS2012 and one of the cool features I am interested in is the Zen Encoding implementation as show [as shown here](http://www.johnpapa.net/zen-coding-in-visual-studio-2012/). Do I enter something like

```
div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a
```

And then does it generate the HTML or am I missing the whole point?

Answer (score 1):

Ok just watched the video [on youtube](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html) and you simply press tab to get the formatting.